# Check for google classroom valid account

Tags: android, google-classroom

I am trying to integrate google classroom in my android application. I am following https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/android link. In the official documentation, I couldnot find any way to ensure that the logged in account has google class room access. So, any way to validate that email has access to google classroom . Any tips and links could be helpful??
For now I am checking for course:
`

```
if (courses != null) {
    for (Course course : courses) {
        names.add(course.getName());
    }
    return names;
    }else {
    Log.d(TAG,"No classroom integration for your account"
}
`
```

I know this is not possible for all the case. Since, some account cannot have course at the beginning.

Comment: Googled for an hours. But still cannot find anything.

Comment: What are you trying to do? After [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth), the email used has access to the API given the right scopes.